# Function Isn't Excluding Repeat Data

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am trying to insert a large amount of data into a table.  The source for the data has the potential to repeat data in what is suppose to be a `UNIQUE` column.  I created the following to insert the data into my table:

```
DECLARE @OrderNum VARCHAR(20), @JobNum VARCHAR(20), @Supplier VARCHAR(100), @OldOrderID int, @UserNum int,
        @OrderID int, @JobID int, @SupplierID int, @ContactID int, @UserID int

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT order_id, job_num, supp_name, user_num
    FROM _po_temp_b

OPEN MY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @OldOrderID, @JobNum, @Supplier, @UserNum
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @OrderNum = order_num
    FROM _po_temp_a
    WHERE order_id = @OldOrderID

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT order_number FROM purchase_order WHERE order_number = @OrderNum)

        SELECT @JobID = j.job_id
          FROM job AS j
         WHERE j.job_number = @JobNum

        SELECT @SupplierID = s.supplier_id
          FROM supplier AS s
         WHERE s.supplier_name = @Supplier

        SELECT @ContactID = sc.contact_id
          FROM supplier_contact AS sc
         WHERE sc.supplier_id = @SupplierID

        SELECT @UserID = ul.user_list_id
          FROM user_list AS ul
         WHERE ul.user_order_number = @UserNum

        INSERT purchase_order(order_number, job_id, supplier_id, contact_id, user_list_id, status_id, notes)
        VALUES (@OrderNum, @JobID, @SupplierID, @ContactID, @UserID, 2, NULL);

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @OldOrderID, @JobNum, @Supplier, @UserNum

END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
GO
```

Now my thought was that the `IF NOT EXISTS` line would stop me from getting a bunch of data repetitions.  However, I am still getting repeat data entries, preventing me from setting the column up as `UNIQUE`, which is what it needs to be.

What exactly is wrong with my setup?  Am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF Syntax is for more than one sql line:

```
IF (whatever)
   BEGIN
       sql line 1
       sql line 2
       .....
       sql line n
   END
```

good luck

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, I don't see a reason for the cursor. It's unclear what column is supposed to be unique, but you can handle your `EXIST` in a `WHERE` clause (i used `NOT IN`) and remove all the variables, and cursor as well.

```
insert into purchase_order (order_number, job_id, supplier_id, contact_id, user_list_id, status_id, notes)
SELECT 
    a.order_id
    ,j.job_id
    ,s.supplier_id
    ,sc.contact_id
    ,ul.user_list_id
    ,2
    ,null
FROM 
    _po_temp_b b
inner join
    _po_temp_a a on a.order_id = b.order_id
inner join
    job j on j.job_number = b.job_num
inner join
    supplier s on s.supplier_name = b.supp_name
inner join 
    supplier_contact sc on sc.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
inner join
    user_list ul on ul.user_order_number = b.user_num
where
    a.order_number not in (SELECT order_number FROM purchase_order)
```

You may need `LEFT` joins... it all depends.

Comment: Setting this up, I get the same issue of still getting repeat entries.  So for some reason, the `WHERE` clause seems to not be doing anything.

Comment: The where clause is definitely limiting the results (assuming there are matching records), but that doesn't mean you don't have duplicate `order_id` in the `_po_temp_b` table. If that's the case, you can use `DISTINCT`